# can't connect to MySQL from localhost on Centos 5

Tags: mysql, domain-name-system, configuration, centos5

I have a fresh install of Centos 5.5 on a new VPS and MySQL seems unable to resolve the keyword 'localhost' - if I use 127.0.0.1 instead it works fine. I checked the /etc/hosts file which is as follows:

```
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 224136.xxxxxxxx.com localhost 224136  224136 localhost.localdomain
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

(I added the last line myself)...but still the localhost keyword isn't recognised. For example when I try to connect to my MySQL server using Navicat over SSH tunnel I get an error:

```
1130 - Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

any ideas what might be the problem, thanks

Comment: Could you please show us 'host -a localhost' or equivalent? (not sure about the command line keys in your OS)

Comment: The 1130 error message you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with a name resolution issue, it merely states that a given IP doesn't have access to MySQL? What happens when you run 'ping localhost'?

Comment: [root@224136 ~]# host -a localhost
Trying "localhost"
Host localhost not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 102 bytes from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53 in 0 ms

Comment: [root@224136 ~]# ping localhost
PING 224136.xxxx.com (xxx.xx.xxx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 224136.xxxxx.com (xxx.xx.xxx.xx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of ruling MySQL is the culprit, please make sure you have root@localhost and root@127.0.0.1 as separate users defined in MySQL.

Do the following to make sure root users can come into MySQL:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1';
```

root@localhost connects via the mysql.sock file

root@l127.0.0.1 connects via TCP/IP

Until you get the networking issues straightened out, you may want to use the --protocol option of the mysql client to specify the protocol (tcp,socket,pipe,memory)

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION

Answer (score 0):

You already have localhost on first line of /etc/hosts. You should remove localhost from line beginning with 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'